# Tikiwiki 16.2 Error while registering new user

Tags: tiki-wiki

I did a fresh install of 16.2 and when I try to register a new user I get the error below. I've re-extracted the zip and reinstalled the database, but I get the same error.

Tikiwiki is in a public_html/tiki folder and I have made no adjustments to it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\Math\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'The RandomLib fallback pseudorandom generator is not installed. Please install it to support secure random numbers' in /home/ghsfhaco/public_html/tiki/vendor/zendframework/zend-math/src/Rand.php:75 Stack trace: #0 /home/ghsfhaco/public_html/tiki/vendor/zendframework/zend-math/src/Rand.php(60): Zend\Math\Rand
getAlternativeGenerator() #1 /home/ghsfhaco/public_html/tiki/vendor/zendframework/zend-captcha/src/AbstractWord.php(354): Zend\Math\Rand
getBytes(32) #2 /home/ghsfhaco/public_html/tiki/vendor/zendframework/zend-captcha/src/AbstractWord.php(340): Zend\Captcha\AbstractWord->generateRandomId() #3 /home/ghsfhaco/public_html/tiki/vendor/zendframework/zend-captcha/src/Image.php(447): Zend\Captcha\AbstractWord->generate() #4 /home/ghsfhaco/public_html/tiki/lib/captcha/captchalib.php(150): Zend\Captcha\Image->generate() #5 /home/ghsfhaco/public_html/tiki/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(171) : eval()'d c in /home/ghsfhaco/public_html/tiki/vendor/zendframework/zend-math/src/Rand.php on line 75`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This also caught us out the other day and it's due to an older version of PHP 5 which hasn't got the mcrypt extension enabled, and we fixed it recently, so there are a few options for you I think:

- Upgrade to php 7 (probably not an option unless it's your own server)
- Enable php-mcrypt for you php (also probably not possible)
- Try again with a recent "daily build" 16.x tarball from [dev.tiki.org](https://dev.tiki.org/Daily+Build)
- Or enable one of the other CAPTCHA methods on `Control panels->Security->Spam Protection`, such as `ReCaptcha` or `CAPTCHA Questions`

HTH

Comment: That must have been it.  I actually just disabled the `Anonymous editors must enter anti-bot code (CAPTCHA)` since I plan to only allow registers users to post anyway.  Thanks for the explanation and the options on how to fix it.  I would upvote, but I only have 12 reputation and that requires 15.